# my .htaccess rewriteRule is failing

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble understanding why this rewrite isn't doing what its told.
NOTE: the first rewrite in my .htaccess file works properly so its not a problem with using mod_rewrite on local host.

i have URIs which i know will be in the format:

```
http://localhost/managerhub/my-manager.php?i=1&t=dashboard
```

when site goes live:

```
http://themanagerhub.com/my-manager.php?i=1&t=dashboard
```

my .htaccess file reads thus:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^my-manager-([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)  my-manager.php?i=$1&t=$2 [PT]
```

To achieve clean URls like:

```
http://localhost/managerhub/my-manager-1-dashboard
```

Ideally i dont really want the first capture group ([0-9]+) since i dont really want the 'i' value in the resultant
clean url  - so ideally id like:

```
http://localhost/managerhub/my-manager-dashboard
```

However ive not even got the rewrite to work so far at all having tried:

- leading forward-slash on the target (though i dont think it was necessary)
- tried changing the '&' ampersand in the target to use &
- removing the [PT] passthru flag replaced with and without [L] flag
- tried most 'least' restrictive character classes in the pattern i.e. (.*) instead of ([0-9]+)
- commented 'out' the first RewriteRule which works flawlessly BTW  - so using the troublesome rule in isolation

Non of these have worked - the second rewrite rule has no effect on the target urls so i cant even see were the discrepancy is. I'm still new to mod_rewrite so sort of rely on an informative fail so i can work out were my reg-ex is wrong but i suspect its just being ignored since im getting 'zilch' back!!

Any help appreciated - maybe with a pointer to my folly.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess file, I'm assuming, is in the "managerhub" directory. That's where those rules need to be. You may need to add a base as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /managerhub/

RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^my-manager-([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)$ my-manager.php?i=$1&t=$2 [L,PT]
```

which you'd need to change when they get to the live site. You can remove the first capture group via:

```
RewriteRule ^my-manager-([a-z]+)$ my-manager.php?t=$1 [L,PT]
```

The `L` flag isn't exactly 100% needed.

Comment: - still not working with your amendments  - i forgot to mention i'd tried rewritebase before unsuccessfully (with and without trailing slash which i read isn't required - thanks anyhow ...

Comment: Could the problem be that not all URIs will match this pattern - i thought that was the point of using a patter match regex??? clutching at straws and no help or ideas ;¬(